# How to make a mailer not repeat itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

So I have managed to create some interesting behavoir that I have no idea how to debug. I have a mailer backed by a model and table. When the user creates a message a method generates an array of contacts to send the email to. We'll pick up there since that has been tested in console.

The model simply itterates through an array of recipients...

```
class ContactMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def send_message(user)
    self.recipients.each do |rec|
      unless rec.include?("@")
        contact = Contact.find(rec)
        to = "\"#{contact.first_name} #{contact.last_name}\" <#{contact.email}>"
      else
        to = rec
        contact = user.contact.new('email' => rec)
      end
     ContactMail.direct_mail(user, self, to, contact).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

It should then make n number of new calls to the ContactMail.direct_mail method.

```
class ContactMail < ActionMailer::Base
  helper :mail
  def direct_mail(user, contact_message, to, contact)
    @user = user
    @contact = contact
    @contact_message = contact_message
    @theme = @contact_message.theme
    mail(:to => to, :subject => contact_message.subject, :from => "no-reply" << @user.website.domain, :reply_to => @user.email)
  end

  ...
end
```

the mail() method renders the view using the @instance variables provided.

```
<%= @user.website.title %>
<%= @user.website.motto %> 
============================================================
<%= @contact_message.message.html_safe.gsub(/<\/?[^><]*>/i, "") %>
============================================================
This message is from <%= @user.first_name << " " << @user.last_name << " of " << @user.business%>
Please reply to <%= @user.email %>
<%= @user.telephone %>
<%= @user.address_l1%>
<%= @user.address_l2 unless @user.address_l2.blank?%>
<%= @user.city << ", " << @user.state << " " << @user.zip %>
<%= @user.website.domain %>
```

All is well and good, I am using MailCatcher to recieve all of the emails and terminal says they were sent.

However, each mail sent after the first the << @instance just keeps piling up onto eachother! It produceses something like

```
Healthy Living
Where massage makes health. 
============================================================
asdfasdfasdfasd
============================================================
This message is from Adam Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC Fluke of Healthy Living LLC
Please reply to fluke.a@gmail.com
504-638-2222
1822 Moss St
Apt E
New Orleans, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119, AL 70119
healthyliving.org
```

(this would be the fifth message sent, it gets progressively worse with each email sent.)

This is what I don't understand, based on my understanding of Mail and method calls, each message sent should be their own unique object and should not be interacting with eachother at all. Yet, the clearly are. This happens with += and <<, in text and html. WTF?

Any thoughts or help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually modifying your instance variables by using `<<`. If you use `+` I think it should work.

Comment: Things got ugly so I deleted the git branch and started again. As part of the rewrite I used + instead.